# sending parameters in relative path results in fail to open stream fil_get_contents

Tags: php

I'm attempting to read a file via `file_get_contents` within my **PHP** script. But for some reason, when I use a relative path to retrieve the contents of a file, it will not let me pass any parameters to the URL.

For example:

```
file_get_contents("path/to/file.php"); // Works great!
file_get_contents("path/to/file.php?option=1"); // Results in a failure
```

How do I get around this without using a proper URL?

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents()` accepts an actual filename as the first parameter. This `path/to/file.php?option=1` is not an actual file on the server.

If you want to retrieve some data from the file for instance, you should first use `file_get_contents("path/to/file.php");` to get the content, pass it to a variable and manipulate the variable to achieve what you want. [Read more](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: Would love to but the content it retrieves is HTML - so it's not exactly easy to manipulate. Any other ideas?

Comment: You can add the content of the file and explain what you intend to do with it to the question.